# Import JSON blob to canvas using FileReader

Tags: fabricjs, filereader

I am trying to allow fabricjs to import a JSON blob string from a .JSON file that I have exported that allows the string to load into the canvas and place. This is for when a user may want to export their canvas work to a different computer by exporting the JSON blob to their downloads in .JSON format and import to another computer to continue for later.

I have been able to figure out how to export the JSON blob with this code here:

```
function exportFile(textData, filename) {
  var filesaver = require('filesaver.js');
  var content = new Blob([textData], {type: "application/json"});
  filesaver.saveAs(content, filename);
}
```

This allows me to use filesaver to write the JSON blob file which contains all of the objects but I am unsure how to import that JSON blob file back in.

Here is my poor attempt at achieving it using FileReader and importing the JSON blob data back into the canvas to show generally how I tried to make it work. It may be a really simple fix, but I am really quite confused by this.

```
$("#import-file-button").on("change", function(e) {
  page.closePanel(null, true);

  // under maintainance 
  var files = e.target.files;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contents = reader.result;
  };

  var readData = reader.readAsText(blob);
  canvas.clear();

  canvas.loadFromJSON(readData, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  utils.centerContent();

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#import-file-button").on("change", function(e) {
  page.closePanel(null, true);

  // under maintainance 
  var files = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contents = reader.result;
      canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(contents), function() {
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
      utils.centerContent();
  };

  reader.readAsText(files);
});
```

You need to read the blob with `readAsText` and inside onload callback add that result to canvas. Make sure `reader.result` is a JSON.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I have found that when I implement this that I have an error when trying to import a file that shows up in the console that says "Uncaught reference error: blob is not defined". Do you know how I may be able to fix this?

Comment: I havent checked that, instead blob you need to pass the file you received, check updated answer.